# Apply a function to every row of a 3-Dimensional numpy array efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance, multidimensional-array

I have this function:

```
def sort_row(row):
    # sums all the pixel values to find a basic pixel "brightness" value
    summed = np.sum(row[:, :4], axis=1)
    min_index = np.argmin(summed)

    # sorts the row up to min_index
    sorted_section = np.argsort(row[:min_index + 1].sum(axis=1))
    # creates the final array by concatenating the new section with the old section
    final_arr = np.concatenate((row[:min_index + 1][sorted_section], row[min_index + 1:]), axis=0)
    return final_arr
```

I want to apply it to every row of a 3 dimensional array.
For example if I had the array:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]])
```

I would want to apply the function first to `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`, then to `[[7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]`.

I was using a for loop to do this like this:

```
    new_array = np.empty_like(image)
    for i, column in enumerate(image):
        new_array[i] = sort_row(column)
```

But I feel like this is very inefficient.

(Oh also I feel like the question is worded wrongly and it isn't a 'row' of an this array)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: instead of concatenate you could write directly into the output (`new_array`) array. I am not sure this is bottleneck though

Comment: I see no one helped you. To increase your chances to get help try to make [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)